# How to design an induction cooktop

Tags: frequency, mains, heat, coil, induction

I'm trying to create my own simplified induction cooktop. If I'd like to use 120V Mains, what determines the current draw of the coil used (is it simply the resistance of the coil)? Also, I understand altering the frequency is a necessity to change the amount of heat produced from the induction process (and hence temperature of the material that has current being inducted on it). How would I go about changing the 50Hz Mains to higher/lower frequencies? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: AC-->DC-->[oscillator]--> high frequencies

Comment: This is a big topic. I am no expert. But the frequencies used for induction heating are roughly 20 kHz -100 kHz range. I am going to vote to close as the question is too broad. I am curious where you live that you have 120V mains and 50 Hz. I thought only British Commonwealth used 50 Hz, and I thought they were all 220V.

Comment: I'm also curious. Half of Japan is 50Hz but I believe they use 100V.

Comment: @mkeith Most of the world uses 50 Hz. Protip for electronics engineers - whatever units and standards are in use in the U.S., the rest of the world generally uses another one. :)

Comment: I ignored the title and provided simple answers to the two questions stated in the body. Interpreted that way, I don't think the question is too broad.

Comment: @pipe, that principle is not sufficiently general to be helpful. But even if it were, it still leaves a mystery, because the US uses 120V and 60 Hz. Your principle suggests that any other country should use 220 or 240V. Anyway, it looks like a majority of the world uses 50 Hz, as you say, but there are quite a few sizeable populations of 60 Hz. US, Mexico, Brazil, part of Japan, South Korea.

Answer (score 2):

> what determines the current draw of the coil used (is it simply the resistance of the coil)?

No. The coil is like the primary of a transformer. The resistance of the coil would cause heating in the coil itself rather than the cooking pan. The secondary current and thus the primary current is determined by:

1. The dimensions of the cooking pan
2. The characteristics of the cooking pan material
3. The distance between the coil and the cooking pan
4. The voltage applied to the coil
5. The frequency of the voltage applied to the coil, because that influences the resistance in the pan due to skin effect
6. Perhaps other factors

> How would I go about changing the 50Hz Mains to higher/lower frequencies?

Power must be applied to the coil using an inverter circuit.

**[Here is a link](http://www.asminternational.org/documents/10192/1849770/ACFAA5C.pdf)**

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find some ideas.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Powerful-yet-simple-induction-heater/

Generally small units have only one mosfet because single ended circuits are good to about 5 kW that is normally more than required, commercial units are about 1,5 kW. Cheap Chinese units here are sold at about 50 $